# Trying to persist entity with detached relationship launch "detached entity passed to persist"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, merge, persist

I need to persist a new entity with a detached relationship but, at the moment of persist(...), I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.Subject
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at Application.method3(Application.java:90)
    at Application.main(Application.java:41)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.Subject
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer$IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3850)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 2 more
```

Entities:
Subject

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAsignaturas", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "nombre", "curso" }) })
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "ASIGNATURAS_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1,       initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre, curso;
    private int creditos;

    // @Transient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subject")
    private Set<Matricula> matriculas;

    public Subject() {
        matriculas = new HashSet<Matricula>();
    }

    public Subject(String nombre, String curso, int creditos) {
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setCurso(curso);
        this.setCreditos(creditos);
        this.matriculas = new HashSet<Matricula>();
    }

    public Matricula addMatricula(Matricula m) {
        m.setSubject(this);
        this.matriculas.add(m);
        return m;
    }

    public void removeMatricula(Matricula m) {
        this.matriculas.remove(m);
    }

    [...]
}
```

Alumno

```
@Entity
public class Alumno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alumno")
    private Set<Matricula> matriculadas;

    public Alumno() {
        super();
        this.matriculadas = new HashSet<Matricula>();
    }

    public Matricula addMatricula(Matricula m) {
        m.setAlumno(this);
        this.matriculadas.add(m);
        return m;
    }

    public void removeMatricula(Matricula m) {
        this.matriculadas.remove(m);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Matricula

```
@IdClass(MatriculaKey.class)
@Entity
public class Matricula implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Alumno alumno;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Subject subject;

    public Matricula() {
        super();
    }

    public Matricula(Alumno a, Subject s) {
        super();
        this.alumno = a;
        this.subject = s;
        this.alumno.addMatricula(this);
        this.subject.addMatricula(this);
    }

    public void addAlumno(Alumno a) {
        a.getMatriculadas().add(this);
        this.alumno = a;
    }

    public void removeAlumno(Alumno a) {
        a.getMatriculadas().remove(this);
        this.setAlumno(null);
    }

    public void addSubject(Subject s) {
        s._getMatriculas().add(this);
        this.subject = s;
    }

    public void removeSubject(Subject s) {
        s._getMatriculas().remove(this);
        this.setSubject(null);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Main code that launch the exception:

```
public class Application {
    Subject sub;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application a = new Application();
        // method2          
        EntityManager em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        a.method2();
        tx.commit();
        if (em.isOpen())
            em.close();
        // method3
        em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        a.method2();
        tx.commit();
        if (em.isOpen())
            em.close();
    }
    //It´s necessary execute this method before to method3, in two different transactions, non in one transaction
    private void method2() {
        this.sub = Jpa.getManager().find(Subject.class, 2L);
    }

    private void method3() {
        Alumno al = new Alumno();
        Matricula m = new Matricula(al, this.sub);
        Jpa.getManager().persist(m); //error. merge doesn´t work nor
    }
}
```

Main code of my poor solution:

```
public class Application {
    Subject sub;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application a = new Application();
        // method2          
        EntityManager em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        a.method2();
        tx.commit();
        if (em.isOpen())
            em.close();
        // method3
        em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        a.method2();
        tx.commit();
        if (em.isOpen())
            em.close();
    }

    private void method2() {
        this.sub = Jpa.getManager().find(Subject.class, 2L);
    }

    private void method3() {
        Alumno al = new Alumno();
        //aux transient subject
        Subject s=new Subject();
        Matricula m = new Matricula(al, s);
        //now, I can persist correctly
        Jpa.getManager().persist(m);
        //replace the aux subject...
        m.removeSubject(s);
        m.addSubject(sub);
        //and update
        Jpa.getManager().merge(m);
    }
}
```

Exists any simpler soluction for this problem?

Miguel

Comment: Can you try merge instead of persist? persist is meant for transient objects.

Comment: Yes, I´ve done it, but it launches the exception again. merge() can insert or update. If the entity is new, merge() does insert but, if the entity is detached, merge() does update. In my case, the entity (Matricula) is new but, It has a relationship (Subject) that is detached, and when the merge() try to insert the new entity (Matricula), try to insert its relationships (Subject and Alumno) too... It does the same as persist(). How to avoid it?

Comment: My poor solution fails in the commit()...